# How do you uninstall everything to do with a specific program (redshiftgui)?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, installed-programs, redshift

I am trying to uninstall `redshiftgui` and `apt -remove` doesn't want to let me, the message is in the screenshot. How do I entirely rid myself of this erroneously downloaded application? (I am on **gnome**.)

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Comment: do you have software center open? or another package manager?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: The easiest way is to restart :D

Comment: @Arun You should add this as an answer

Comment: Another application, e.g. software center, package manager is already using the installation command: dpkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PC can't remove it because another app is using the **apt**.

You can **detect and kill that process** which is using apt (it can be software center or another terminal installing something with dpkg etc.).

But if you want an easy way: **restart the computer** :)

---

Here is the code for removing all things about redshift:

```
sudo apt purge '*redshift*'
```